# How to smooth a graph in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I plotted a diagram with pyqtgraph and now I'm trying to "smooth" the graph (instead of zigzag), which (I read) should work with `antialias`, but I couldn't find the right "position" to make it work.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=('b'), width=2)
        styles = {'color':'r', 'font-size':'15px'}

        self.graphWidget.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)  # AttributeError: setConfigOptions

        self.graphWidget.setLabel('left', 'x-values', **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel('bottom', 'y-values', **styles)
        
        x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y_values = [2, 1, 2, 4, 3]

        self.graphWidget.plot(x_values, y_values, pen=pen, symbol='o',
                                   symbolSize=8, symbolPen='k', symbolBrush='k')

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I also tried this, but without success (doesn't do anything different):

```
pen = pg.mkPen(color=('b'), width=2, antialias=True)
```

```
self.graphWidget.plot(x_values, y_values, pen=pen, symbol='o',
                                   symbolSize=8, symbolPen='k', symbolBrush='k', antialias=True)
```

I would be really glad if anyone could tell me how to use this right (or if there are other options to smooth the graph).

I'm using Python 3.8, PyQt5 5.15.0, PyCharm 2020.2 and Linux Mint 19.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of the anti-aliasing attribute is not to make the drawn curves smooth but to make the painting smooth. If you want smooth curves then you must interpolate the points, for example using `scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline`:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.plot()

    def plot(self):
        pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.graphWidget.setBackground("w")
        pen = pg.mkPen(color=("b"), width=2)
        styles = {"color": "r", "font-size": "15px"}

        self.graphWidget.setLabel("left", "x-values", **styles)
        self.graphWidget.setLabel("bottom", "y-values", **styles)

        x_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y_values = [2, 1, 2, 4, 3]

        xnew = np.linspace(min(x_values), max(x_values), 100)
        spl = make_interp_spline(x_values, y_values, 3)
        ynew = spl(xnew)

        self.graphWidget.plot(xnew, ynew, pen=pen)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the [documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_options.html#pyqtgraph.setConfigOptions), you have to set antialiasing for the *module*:

```
pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)
```

Alternatively, since all `pyqtgraph` graphs are actually subclasses of [QGraphicsView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html), set the appropriate [`renderHints()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#renderHints-prop):

```
self.graphWidget.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
```